# Unreal 5 Strange Global Illumination Effects

Tags: lighting, unreal-5

As stated in the title, I am having some strange effects with global illumination. I am using Lumen, and I have no active post process volumes (I have one which is set to "editor only")

I have a player actor with a spotlight attached to the blueprint, set to 20 lumens (I have tried playing with the lumen value, but it doesn't seem to change the effects) and am having weird issues with the lighting.

In [this video](https://youtu.be/M2cUUzvmcEI), you can see that when you look up a bit, the lighting appears to dim, which is the opposite of what I would expect (I would expect the global illuminator to get brighter, as there are less surfaces "reflecting" light back to the camera)

I have also noticed that while looking up, as in the video, if you back up (same camera angle) so that a closer ceiling is within view, it will brighten again.

How can I fix this unexpected behavior?

Please let me know if there is any other information needed.